# MySQL Substring Update Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on a database and am confused on why this script is not working. I am in a table called listing and attempting to update a row, based on a substring withing the URL.

```
Update listing
SET Vendor_ID = 8
WHERE Listing_URL LIKE '%amazon%'
```

Essentially Vendor_ID, is a foreign key and I want to update it based on if amazon is within the URL. I have also tried:

```
Update listing
SET Vendor_ID = 8
WHERE SUBSTRING(Listing_URL, 13, 6) = "amazon"
```

However, neither seem to be working. Any thoughts?

Comment: Define "not working"

Comment: The first should work if `amazon` is anywhere in the URL.

Comment: None of the rows are updating when I run the script

Comment: Are you using a case-sensitive collation? Does the URL have lowercase `amazon` in it?

Comment: Works for me: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d69x4G5qMPoHJEAXzrxaaP/0

Comment: Since `Vendor_ID` is a foreign key, does the value `8` exist in the parent table? If not, you should be getting an error.

Comment: What does `select Listing_URL from listing WHERE Listing_URL LIKE '%amazon%'` show?

Comment: Barmar: Yes the value 8 exists in the parent table. Also when I run that script I am getting a list of all of the URL's containing amazon

Answer (score 0):

Please add schema name before table name like this:

```
Update <schema_name>.listing
SET Vendor_ID = 8
WHERE Listing_URL LIKE '%amazon%'
```